# Plot each individual character from a sequence of letters

Tags: r, scatter-plot

So I have a string of letters but only 4 unique letters in total.  Let's say G, T, A, C.  I want to plot each occurrence of each letter in a scatterplot so that the sequence is listed and for each letter there is a point above it that corresponds to that letter.  Something like this...

[image]

A possible start for string of characters would be,

```
sample(LETTERS[1:4], 20, replace = T)
```

Comment: `plot(as.numeric(factor(x)), pch=3, xaxt="n") ;
axis(1, at=seq_along(x), labels=x)`

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE)

plot(as.numeric(factor(x)), pch=3, xaxt="n", yaxt="n") 
axis(1, at=seq_along(x), labels=x, cex.axis=0.75, lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1)
axis(2, at=seq_along(x))
```

Which produces

[image]

`as.numeric(factor(.))` is used to convert the letters to numeric for easy plotting

`xaxt`, and `yaxt` are used to suppress the default axis labels 
(you could use `axes=FALSE` and then use `box()` at the end)

`pch` is used to give the cross symbol - try `plot(1:22, pch=1:22, cex=2, col=1:22)`

`axis` is used to add in the axis labels, where `at` is used to specify the position

`cex.axis` adjusts the size of the text labels

`lwd` suppress the axis line being redrawn on top of the box and `lwd.ticks` allows the ticks still to be drawn (if you omit this and use `lwd=0` then the ticks will also be omitted)